# If a trait does not appear to be advantageous to organism, why does the organism have it?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection

Why do organisms have some traits that do not appear to have any evolutionary advantage?

Comment: Also, let me know if this question should be merged should be merged with this thread: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/if-a-trait-would-be-advantageous-to-an-organism-why-hasnt-it-evolved. They are fairly similar.

Comment: You could have answered there itself.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Fair enough, the reason I didn't is because I figured the question "Why didn't X trait evolve if it would be advantageous" and "Why did X trait evolve if it isn't advantageous" are different enough to warrant two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why an organism might have a trait that does not appear to be beneficial.

1. The trait is actually advantageous even if it does not appear to be.
2. The trait is a byproduct of another trait, which is beneficial. Not all traits are the product of direct selection; traits that are byproducts of other traits are known as "[spandrels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spandrel_(biology))", a trait coined by [Stephen J. Gould and Richard Lewontin](http://faculty.washington.edu/lynnhank/GouldLewontin.pdf)
3. The trait was fixed by some process other than natural selection, such as genetic drift. Genetic drift can fix traits that are neutral or even evolutionarily disadvantageous.

Comment: Also, the trait may have been beneficial at some point but no longer is. See: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/is-there-a-name-for-the-evolutionary-loss-of-vestigial-structures